# php memcache on iis 7 not working

Tags: php, iis-7, memcached, php-ini

I have installed memcache by following this article:

http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/installing-memcache-on-windows-for-php/

In a nutshell, I add the php_memcache.dll to my php/ext/ directory, IIS picks it up fine, but when i go into the php.ini file and add the line of code:

extension=php_memcache.dll

it doesn't show up in the phpinfo.php file.

Anyone know why,

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Check the results of `phpinfo();` and find "Thread Safety" - you'll likely find it is "disabled".  If that is the case, you'll need to make sure you have the "nts" (not thread-safe) version of the php_memcache.dll (the site http://downloads.php.net/pierre/, for example, links to both)

Comment: @PhillHealey you must download and use the dll that matches how PHP was compiled; this isn't a runtime setting.  If thread safety reads "disabled" then you should download an NTS DLL.